# С какой целью нужно объявление функции внутри функции?

Tags: python, функции

В питоновском коде несколько раз встречал подобные конструкции:

```
def spam():
...
    def eggs():
    ...
```

Т.е. мы объявляем функцию `eggs()` внутри функции `spam()`. С какой целью нужны такие конструкции? Единственное, что приходит в голову -- это области видимости, т.к. функция `eggs()` не будет видна за пределами функции `spam()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Причина:

Область видимости. Возможно, вы для упрощения кода внутри функции захотели его обернуть в функцию, но в то же время, не хотите чтобы внутренние вспомогательные функции торчали наружу.

Например у вас есть функция, которая принимает в параметры списки, делает над ними операции и возвращает результат. Код внутри повторяется и нужно что-то с этим делать:

```
def pow_and_sum(items_1, items_2, items_3) -> int:
    items_1 = map(int, items_1)
    items_2 = map(int, items_2)
    items_3 = map(int, items_3)
    
    items_1 = map(lambda x: pow(x, 2), items_1)
    items_2 = map(lambda x: pow(x, 2), items_2)
    items_3 = map(lambda x: pow(x, 2), items_3)
    
    return sum(items_1) + sum(items_2) + sum(items_3)
```

Обычное решение повторяющего кода - обернуть его в функцию, а т.к. та функция очень специфична и мы не хотим чтобы она была видна глобально, создаем ее в локальной видимости:

```
def pow_and_sum(items_1, items_2, items_3) -> int:
    def do(items):
        items = map(int, items)
        items = map(lambda x: pow(x, 2), items)
        return sum(map(int, items))

    return do(items_1) + do(items_2) + do(items_3)
    
    
print(pow_and_sum('123', [1, 2], ['1', 4]))  # 36
```

---

А также это используется в:

1. [Замыкания (closure)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

   ```
   # multiplier возвращает функцию умножения на n
   def multiplier(n):
       def mul(k):
           return n * k

       return mul

   # mul3 - функция, умножающая на 3
   mul3 = multiplier(3)
   print(mul3(3), mul3(5))  # 9 15
   ```
2. [Карринг (currying)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

   ```
   def my_sum(x, y, z):
       return x + y + z

   def foo(x):
       def a(y):
           def b(z):
               return my_sum(x, y, z)
           return b
       return a

   print(foo(1)(2)(3))        # 6
   print(foo("1")("2")("3"))  # 123
   ```
3. [Декораторы (decorator)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

   ```
   def makebold(fn):
       def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
           return "<b>" + fn(*args, **kwargs) + "</b>"
       return wrapped

   def makeitalic(fn):
       def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
           return "<i>" + fn(*args, **kwargs) + "</i>"
       return wrapped

   def upper(fn):
       def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
           return fn(*args, **kwargs).upper()
       return wrapped

   @makebold
   @makeitalic
   @upper
   def hello(text):
       return text

   print(hello('Hello World!'))  # <b><i>HELLO WORLD!</i></b>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Довольно немало функций которые получают параметром другую функцию. Например таким образом удобно оперировать с коллекциями. Например, не привязываясь к языку, можно написать coollection.where(myFunc) и результатом будет коллекция отфильтрованная по условию в myFunc.
2. Функция может быть колбеком, это удобно если у нас есть замыкания, например типичный пример использования - передать в какой нибудь объект функцию которая как то модифицирует поля текущего объекта из которого мы ее передаем. Например:

   ```
   var progress = 0;
   new obj((increment)->{progress += increment}).start();
   ```

   В данном случае у нас создается новый объект которому мы передаем колбек для увеличения счетчика прогресса и запускаем этот объект методом start();
3. Ну и иногда да, просто удобно не захламлять общую область видимости функцией котрая нужна только в одном месте.

А, еще например в js такое определение позволяет создавать объекты с методами.

Comment: но изначальный вопрос про [tag:python] был, а не про [tag:java] или [tag:js]

Comment: @mymedia тем не менее, как примечание в конце вопроса, это не плохо